# Context-sensitive bash completion changes wildcard behavior

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Somewhere along the way I've fallen into the habit of hitting tab twice after using a wildcard in commands like mv or rm, which by default causes bash to show the list of files that would match the wildcard expansion.  For example:

```
  {~/bin}-> ls p*<TAB>
  pnuke         pscp          pssh          
  prsync        pslurp        pssh-askpass
```

However, when using the bash_completion package in Debian Jessie, this behavior has changed, and the default behavior when completing a filename is to replace any wildcards with the first (and only the first) file that matches the expansion.  With bash_completion installed, if I use the same example as above, my command line changes to look like this after hitting tab:

```
  {~/bin}-> ls pnuke
```

Of all the possible actions bash could have taken in this situation, this seems like the least useful.  Is there a way to get back the default readline file completion behavior, while still getting all the other goodies that bash_completion provides when completing something that is not a file name?  Or if not the default behavior, can I at least make it do something helpful?  (Even doing nothing at all would be more helpful behavior than this.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you know you can get the desired behavior by typing `ls p` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> instead of `ls p*` + <kbd>Tab</kbd>?

Alternatively you can type `ls p*` + <kbd>Alt - !</kbd> or `ls p*` + <kbd>Ctrl - x</kbd> + <kbd>!</kbd>.

Note that <kbd>Alt - !</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl - x</kbd> + <kbd>!</kbd> are bound to **complete-command** and **possible-command-completions**, respectively. You can rebind <kbd>Tab</kbd> to **complete-command** via `bind '\C-i:complete-command'`. This will give you your desired glob expansion but will probably screw up completion for other things.

Hopefully there is a better solution. If I knew what version of Bash introduced the change, I'd have a better chance of finding one.

Answer (score 0):

The bash version isn't very relevant, this behaviour is part of bash-completion, a separate project.

uninstalling this package or editting its config files will give you the desired default behaviour